# function to return rest of the array

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have two functions,  generateFunction return an array with 6 elements `[(5,2),(5,1),(5,0),(4,4),(4,3),(4,2)]` and the another distributeFunction returns an array with two choices of two elements `[[(5,2),(4,3)], [(5,1),(5,0)]]` for example

how do I make a function that in this case returns the elements that have not been chosen? in this example
`[(4,4),(4,2)]`??
thanks

Comment: Is there a specific issue? The solution is going to depend on your specific situation. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the chosen list, convert the choices to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) and then find the difference between it and the chosen values:

```
choices = [(5,2),(5,1),(5,0),(4,4),(4,3),(4,2)]
chosen = [[(5,2),(4,3)], [(5,1),(5,0)]]

# flatten chosen
chosen = [t for c in chosen for t in c]

# convert choices to a set
choices = set(choices)

# find the difference
diff = list(choices.difference(chosen))
print(diff)
```

Output:

```
[(4, 2), (4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the class `set` you can easily get the difference:

```
def difference(generated, chosen):
    chosen0 = set(chosen[0])
    chosen1 = set(chosen[1])
    generated = set(generated)   
    
    return list(generated - chosen0 - chosen1)

generated = [(5,2),(5,1),(5,0),(4,4),(4,3),(4,2)]
chosen = [[(5,2),(4,3)], [(5,1),(5,0)]]

print(difference(generated, chosen))
#[(4, 2), (4, 4)]
```

More information [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).